# What is the little bar on top of the Review Pages?

Tags: support, review-queues

I recently gained the privilege of reviewing first posts and late answers. I can't quite figure out what the little bar on top of the page means. When I mouse over it, I see my badge progress (which has four easily understandable bar graphs) but I don't see any correlation between the two (other than the fact that I've done 7 reviews in this queue.)

What is this little bar? More specifically, what does the spacing between the two marks mean? Is it a histogram of some sort?

[image: review bar expanded]

Comment: its a graph to your next shiny new badge

Comment: I understand the bars in the grey Badge Progress box. I don't understand the bar above the grey box. See my edit.

Comment: its a graph to your next shiny new badge in this category (e.g. First Posts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also a progress bar, except that one goes to 1,000 always (the gold Steward badge), whereas the bar in the grey pop-up box only goes to the silver badge (250) until you've earned it, and then switches to the gold badge (1,000).

The grey line on the other bar is the 250 mark where you'd earn the silver badge.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it would be easier to understand for those with more reviews (7/1000 in this case is only one pixel).